# How to override method in library?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, overriding

That's my gradle with library

```
api 'com.simplify:ink:1.0.2'
```

In the library file, which is read-only `Inkview.java`
This method is triggered, when every popup, showkeyboard is displayed.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        clear();
    }
```

I would like to override it to just not call this method, or call it whether I need it.
I have created `InkView.kt`

```
fun InkView.onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {

}
```

but it is triggered by default anyway.
How to apply this proper?

EDIT:
After first post I have created new class MyInkView and add it to `.xml` file.

```
    <com.myApplication.fragment.extensions.MyInkView
        android:id="@+id/inkView"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

error when enter to the fragment:

```
Error inflating class com.myApplication.fragment.extensions.MyInkView
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.myApplication.fragment.extensions.MyInkView.<init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

If I add `attributeSet` as null
then error is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
```

Second Edit:

```
class MyInkView: InkView {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context): super(context)
    // include any other constructors you need based on the ones in the superclass

    fun InkView.onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Doesn't override anything, and doesn't give crash. It works like before.

```
class MyInkView: InkView {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context): super(context)
    // include any other constructors you need based on the ones in the superclass

   override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

error log:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
```

clear method from inkView

```
// clean up existing bitmap
       if (bitmap != null) {
           bitmap.recycle()
       }

       // init bitmap cache
       this.bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
       canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

       // notify listeners
       for (listener in listeners) {
           listener.onInkClear()
       }

       invalidate()
       isEmpty = true

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin extension functions are statically resolved, and can't override member functions.

If you want to override a member function of `InkView`, you'll need to create a new class that extends from it.

For example:

```kotlin
class MyInkView(context: Context): InkView(context) {
    override fun InkView.onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

To allow Android to instantiate the class properly, you probably also need the additional two-arg constructor:

```kotlin
class MyInkView: InkView {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context): super(context)
    // include any other constructors you need based on the ones in the superclass

    override fun InkView.onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: check my comment. The goal is to add it to .xml file, but InkView inherit after View, so what is its problem?:)

Comment: You might need to provide additional constructors, one for each of the constructors that exists in the `InkView` class. I'm not sure which constructor the system will use when trying to create your class.

Comment: I have edited post one more time. You are right it needs somekind of constructors, but I think problem is somewhere else. Normally when I create custom layout

Comment: I know what's going on. Method onSize~ make clear which I give in post right now and it gives error. But I can't override it and reasign any value like bitmap etc. :C :)

Comment: Thank you for an answer, I have created another topic to make it clear. Thanks :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73623469/is-there-an-option-to-override-parameters-methods-in-library