# Is there an option to override parameters, methods in library?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-custom-view

According to this topic:
[How to override method in library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73621464/how-to-override-method-in-library/73621534?noredirect=1#comment130008775_73621534)

I would like to override some methods and variables from `InkView`.
Is it possible? :)

I have created class:

```
class MyInkView: InkView {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int = 0): super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context): super(context)
    // include any other constructors you need based on the ones in the superclass
    var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

   override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {

       // clean up existing bitmap
       if (bitmap != null) {
           bitmap.recycle()
       }

       // init bitmap cache
       bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
       canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

       // notify listeners
       for (listener in listeners) {
           listener.onInkClear()
       }

       invalidate()
       isEmpty = true
    }
}
```

Of course it gives some error of accidental overrides:

```
Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (getBitmap()Landroid/graphics/Bitmap;):

Cannot access 'canvas': it is invisible (private in a supertype) in 'MyInkView'

Cannot access 'listeners': it is invisible (private in a supertype) in 'MyInkView'
```

Entire `InkView`
https://justpaste.it/27rn0

If I make it empty it doesn't create any bitmap and I have error with this.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.isRecycled()' on a null object reference
```

1 EDIT:

I make this function:

```
    fun getBitmap(backgroundColor: Int, lineColor: Int): Bitmap? {
        val currentPaint: Paint = readPrivateField("paint") ?: return null
        val linePaint = Paint(currentPaint)
        linePaint.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(lineColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        val currentBitmap: Bitmap = readPrivateField("bitmap") ?: return null
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val bitmapCanvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        bitmapCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)
        bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(currentBitmap, 0f, 0f, linePaint)
        return bitmap
    }
```

Previously without custom class view it worked like this in `.extension` :

```
fun InkView.getBitmap(backgroundColor: Int, lineColor: Int): Bitmap? {
    val currentPaint: Paint = readPrivateField("paint") ?: return null
    val linePaint = Paint(currentPaint)
    linePaint.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(lineColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    val currentBitmap: Bitmap = readPrivateField("bitmap") ?: return null
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val bitmapCanvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    bitmapCanvas.drawColor(backgroundColor)
    bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(currentBitmap, 0f, 0f, linePaint)
    return bitmap
}
```

Unfortunately it make crash during saving this bitmap.

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field paint in class Lcom/application/core/view/MyInkView; (declaration of 'com.application.core.view.MyInkView' appears in base.apk!classes2.dex)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
        at com.application.core.view.MyInkView.getBitmap(MyInkView.kt:50)
```

That's where this error occurs:

```
inline fun <T : Any, reified R> T.readPrivateField(name: String): R? {
    val field = javaClass.getDeclaredField(name)   -<<<< CRASH
    field.isAccessible = true
    val result = field.get(this) as? R
    field.isAccessible = false
    return result
}
```

Comment: Please don't make a duplicate of the (relatively) same question. If you wish to improve the previous question, you can edit it and add/remove whatever you desire. Unless I'm misreading, these really do appear to be the same question.

Comment: IMO, last question was about creating custom layout and override method in general. This is with specific case with overriding variables with created before Extended class so it is different. When I edit my previous question it will be misunderstanding with answers a person gave me. Thanks :)

Comment: This class does not allow you to override what canvas it's using or to inspect all its listeners, since those are private members. Not sure what you're trying to do to this class, since you've merely hoisted the code out of `clear()` into this function that's already calling `clear()` in the superclass.

Comment: I just want to edit this clear() method with something different. It clears my data (inkview) when I popup or show keyboard.

Comment: I wanted to put there somekind of if, to specify when I put it true/false do it or not, to have better access to execute this method. Now it is done over and over after every popup or other little change on the screen, which is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd attempt what you described in the comments. It disables the `clear()` function, but allows you to manually clear it by calling `forceClear()`.

```
class MyInkView: InkView {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int = 0): super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context): super(context)

    override fun clear() {}

    fun forceClear() = super.clear()
}
```

However, I suspect you actually need to allow it to clear if the view truly changes size, because otherwise the bitmap will be the wrong size for the view. I would do this instead, exit the function early when the size has not actually changed. Also ignore sizes of 0 in case there's ever a transitionary size 0 state.

```
class MyInkView: InkView {
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int = 0): super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context): super(context)

    private var lastAcceptedWidth = -1
    private var lastAcceptedHeight = -1
    private var preventClear = false;

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        preventClear = (w == lastAcceptedWidth && h == lastAcceptedHeight) || w == 0 || h == 0
        if (!preventClear) {
            lastAcceptedWidth = w
            lastAcceptedHeight = h
        }
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
        preventClear = false
    }

    override fun clear() {
        if (!preventClear) super.clear()
    }
}
```

Comment: This... this one is super hyper good clever idea. I will think about it and inform about the result. Man cool! :)

Comment: It quite works I had to change for (w == lastAcceptedWidth | | h == lastAcceptedHeight), because it saves different. But it works with  ||. Unfortunately it crashes during saving. I have made edit in main post. Thanks in advance.  P.S. During writing this post, maybe I should just define these values in MyInkView.

Comment: Hmm... is it possible to provide the values from InkView to MyInkView like you did with super.method() ?

Comment: Ok what  I have done it is just initValues() when apply getBitMap and it is ok. Thanks:)

Comment: Regarding your question, we only use `super` on methods that are not private/package-private in the superclass. You don't use `super` for fields, but  they still can't be private/package-private if you want to access them. That is why you cannot access `canvas` and `listeners`.